# MYsql Update sequence number in order column for multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I need to update the display_order column with sequence for numbers for array of ids
Consider the following array of  Ids (13, 6, 5, 19, 1, 3, 2), for this ids i need to update the order column

DB

```
+----+-------+---------------+
| id | name  | display_order |
+----+-------+---------------+
| 1  | cat1  | 3             |
+----+-------+---------------+
| 2  | cat2  | 4             |
+----+-------+---------------+
| 5  | cat5  | 6             |
+----+-------+---------------+
| 6  | cat6  | 1             |
+----+-------+---------------+
| 13 | cat13 | 2             |
+----+-------+---------------+
```

Currently im using the following query

```
UPDATE categories
   SET display_order = CASE id 
                      WHEN 13 THEN 1 
                      WHEN 6 THEN 2 
                      WHEN 5 THEN 3 
                      WHEN 19 THEN 4 
                      WHEN 1 THEN 5 
                      WHEN 3 THEN 6 
                      WHEN 2 THEN 7 
                      
                      END
 WHERE id IN (13, 6, 5, 19, 1, 3, 2);
```

Currently im looping the ids in PHP to generate the "case when" statement, the array may come with more Ids. Is there any alternative way to do it in Mysql so i can avoid looping.

Comment: By what logic are you setting the order in the front end?

Comment: You're also asking us to provide SQL code to replace a process the front end is doing, but *you didn't tell us what the front end is actually doing* so your question can't really be answered..

Answer (score 2):

```sql
UPDATE categories
SET display_order = FIND_IN_SET(id, '13,6,5,19,1,3,2')
WHERE id IN (13, 6, 5, 19, 1, 3, 2);
```

Pay attention - the ids list in `FIND_IN_SET` is one string literal without spaces after commas. `id` is converted to string before searching, and the searching is performed as textual one.

If you want to transfer ids list into the query once you may use the next form:

```sql
UPDATE categories
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT '13,6,5,19,1,3,2' ids ) ids 
SET categories.display_order = FIND_IN_SET(categories.id, ids.ids)
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(categories.id, ids.ids);
```

but it will be slower due to textual comparing (and hence full table scan - no indices can be used for this query). Do it on compact (less than ~1000 rows) table only.

Comment: But it doesnt really answer the question *Is there any alternative way to do it in Mysql so i can avoid looping* because the looping still used to build the set string?

Comment: @CaiusJard IMPLODE function usage is not "looping".

Comment: Having the need to use `FIND_IN_SET` in this way often indicates a code smell.

Comment: @Akina we don't know what the front end is doing but we can assume looping because the OP says that's what they want to avoid. Sure aint MySQL doing any looping with a CASE, so...  I maintain my belief that the OP has asked the wrong question, or an XY question; they made the decision to solve something in SQL, but it's probably not SQL's job to solve it

Comment: @CaiusJard OP tells that "Currently im looping the ids in PHP to generate the "case when" statement". As I understand he have an array where $ar[0]=13, $ar[1]=6, .. and so on, and he loops over this array for to add keywords WHEN and THEN and to combine the array into one string to be inserted into the query text. Maybe I'm wrong... I simply show another form of provided query which does not contain detailed CASE.

Comment: Indeed.. I was just pointing out that swapping out the CASE WHEN for a bespoke/MySQL only equivalent might not answer the specific question asked, however wrong that question might be

Answer (score 0):

You should maintain the `id` values and their mappings in a separate table `display_orders`:

```
id | val
1  | 5
2  | 7
3  | 6
5  | 3
6  | 2
13 | 1
19 | 4
```

Then, just do an update inner join:

```sql
UPDATE categories c
INNER JOIN display_orders d
    ON d.id = c.id
SET
    display_order = d.val
WHERE
    c.id IN (1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 13, 19);
```

Comment: I'm struggling to see the advantage of a separate table

Comment: I'm struggling to _not_ see the advantage of a separate table, unless the handful of values in the `CASE` expression are one-offs, and would never be expected to change.

Comment: Nope, you've lost me

Comment: Relational information, such as mapping `id` to something else, generally belongs in a table, not in the query itself.  The `WHERE` clause I have _might_ even be optional, if the OP wants to do a blanket mapping of all `id` values.

Comment: But aren't you just moving the CASE query to the mappings table? Generally, mappings are only required where the relationship is not 1 to 1.

Comment: Re-read the above comment.  It's OK to store relational data in a table, but that information generally doesn't belong in the query itself, because it becomes a maintenance nightmare for whoever inherits the code, and also makes the code brittle and error-prone.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the reply. Is there another way to implement this without moving the display_order to separate table.

Comment: @sethuraman Not of which I'm aware, maybe Strawberry or someone else can post another answer though...

Comment: @sethuraman please decide what your question is. You said (in the question) "is there a way that can avoid looping" - yes. This way. Put your IDs in a table then you don't loop anything, you just maintain the table  and issue a single update. I think what you should *actually* be doing is taking whatever logic your front end does to generate the order in the first place and putting that into a query.. Or if it cannot be thus because e.g. it's user gneerated and the user is dragging things in a screen to dictate some custom order then just fire an update query every time they drag

Comment: (i.e. in some way it doesn't make sense to maintain a separate table then use that table to make edits to the main table; just edit the main table by the same logic you edit the separate table). I think youre being given good answers *to the wrong question*

Answer (score 0):

You can use insert into on duplicate key update.

for example:

```sql
INSERT INTO categories(id, display_order)
VALUES(13,1),
(6,2),
(5,3),
(19,4),
(1,5),
(3,6),
(2,7) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    id = VALUES(id),
    display_order = VALUES(display_order);
```